# Why is my Wither Skeleton Farm not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The light level on the farm is 0 except where the portal is.

| [image: Under the Farm] | [image: Under the Farm] |
| --- | --- |
| Click for larger images |  |

I never went into the portal on the farm, and this is what I saw in this tutorial from a year ago:

Comment: Are you in a nether fortress biome? From your screenshot it doesn't look like it...

Comment: Yes, it is. Part of my farm is above a nether fortress. Even if it is not, it should have spawned other mobs, but nothing is spawning on the farm.

Comment: but are mobs still spawning outside of your farm? Also, nether fortress locations are very much limited to the actual structure and don't extend infinitely up/down.

Comment: Yea, they are spawning around it, but none on it. But, I thought there was a bounding box around the nether fortress which allows wither skeleton to spawn around and above the nether fortress.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the fortress's inner bounding box is the best place for withers to spawn, and a crossroad section is better again. From personal experience, I've always used the crossroads section and never had issues with spawns. The video says it doesn't need to be spawn-proofed, but if you have mobs spawning around the farm and not in it, it might be worth some spawn-proofing. There are a few things you can try:

1. Fly/run over 256+ blocks away from the farm and back quickly, to spawn reset the chunks (or if in creative, kill all mobs)
2. Spawn proof the rest of the area outside/above the farm (noticed a magma slime in one of the screenshots, and endermen will spawn inside the spawning sphere if there is room to do so)
3. If you're in creative mode, fly through the world (F3+N) between your AFK spot and the farm to look for empty spawnable space.
4. Check if the mob bridge in the overworld isn't full and withers are stuck there.
5. Check portals are linked. Could be sending your withers to the deep dark.

Comment: Hi SheepishMonster, welcome to Arqade! This reads more as a useful and helpful comment than an answer, as it doesn't give an explanation as to why no Withers are spawning in the OP's contraption. Please take our [Tour] to familiarize yourself with the concept of this platform. We're looking forward to seeing more of your contributions.

Comment: @Joachim I believe tips like this are part of the answer, and the lack of formatting of the comments makes it much more useful when posted as an answer. An answer is a solution to a problem, and these are steps that can be taken to potentially solve the problem. Thus, it is a potential answer. If I recall correctly, potential answers tend to, and should, be put in the answer's section.

Comment: @Samstercraft But it doesn't answer the question (why this particular setup is not working). As for the rest: that is simply how this platform works, whether you agree with it or not. I realize comments don't allow for markup and extensive advice, but they should simply not be used for it. Similarly, answers should be used for true answers.